# IOS flicker in SDK6.1 but not in 5.X or earlier

Tags: ios, multithreading, uialertview, flicker

I updated my app which was created one year later for SDK 5.X, but now, I get a terrible problem.In the app, using MBProgressHUD to download files from the server, and show an UIAlerView when it finished. but, thus, the view flicker, Someone saied that the UIAlertView should disappeared on the main thread, my code is like this :

```
    NSMutableDictionary *dic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
MBProgressHUD *hud = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithWindow:[[WNMAppDelegate appDelegate] window]];
hud.labelText = @"Please wait...";
[[[WNMAppDelegate appDelegate] window] addSubview:hud];
[hud showAnimated:YES whileExecutingBlock:^{
    [self progressHudMethodForCheckIn:dic];
} completionBlock:^{
    [hud removeFromSuperview];
    [hud release];
    if ([[dic allKeys] count])
    {
        NSString *key = [[dic allKeys] objectAtIndex:0];
        [self alertMessage:[dic objectForKey:key] withTitle:key];
    }
    else
    {
        [self alertMessage:@"Succeed sign in" withTitle:@"Nice"];
    }
}];
[dic release];

- (void)alertMessage:(NSString *)message withTitle:(NSString *)title{
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                      initWithTitle:title
                      message:(NSString *)message
                      delegate:nil
                      cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                      otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
[alert release];
```

}

can someone help me? Thank you.